# How to add unique popups to each GeoJSON polygon in Folium using Python

Tags: python, leaflet, popup, geojson, folium

I am trying to create a Folium map with buildings. I want to add a popup to each building based on its corresponding `openbare_ruimte` property. However, the code that I wrote adds the same popup to all buildings.

I have consulted several threads on this issue ([#1023](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/1023), [#1060](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/1060), [#popups](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Popups.ipynb), [#popups2](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/BibMartin/4b9784461d2fa0d89353)), but have been unable to get it to work.

Does anyone know how I can add each buildings' `openbare_ruimte` property to its popup?

```
import json
import requests
import folium

url = "http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=json&count=25&srsName=epsg:4326&typeName=bag:verblijfsobject&cql_filter=%28bag:woonplaats=%27Groningen%27%29"
js_data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)


m = folium.Map(location=[53.2193835, 6.5665018], zoom_start=13)

fg = folium.map.FeatureGroup(name='Buildings').add_to(m)

#Add the polygons features to the FeatureGroup layer
for feature in js_data['features']:
    fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(feature['properties']['pandgeometrie']))

#Add popups to the FeatureGroup layer
for feature in js_data['features']:
    fg.add_child(folium.Popup(feature['properties']['openbare_ruimte']))


folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want each building to provide a popup showing its address (street I suppose).

This code seems to do what you desire:

```py
import json
import requests
import folium

url = "http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=json&count=25&srsName=epsg:4326&typeName=bag:verblijfsobject&cql_filter=%28bag:woonplaats=%27Groningen%27%29"
js_data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)


m = folium.Map(location=[53.2193835, 6.5665018], zoom_start=13)

fg = folium.map.FeatureGroup(name='Buildings').add_to(m)

for feature in js_data['features']:
    b = folium.GeoJson(feature['properties']['pandgeometrie'])
    b.add_child(folium.Popup(feature['properties']['openbare_ruimte']))
    fg.add_child(b)


folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

and you get, as an example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks...! Status 404 with the provided link... Maybe out of date?

Comment: How does `folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)` know what had to added to `m`?